# Creating Highlight in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, highlight

I need to select a group of text in a web page by clicking the left click of the mouse. When I release the left click, one menu apppears. How to select the group of text in Selenium?

Comment: Can you post the html or url and elaborate what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to select a group of text by clicking the left click of the mouse . When I release the left click of the mouse one menu window appears. my doubt is: How to automate the click and release of the mouse action using selenium webdriver

Comment: Nitin Please tell me how to automate clicking the left click and holding the click to a certain point. and On release the left click the menu appears. I know how to handle the menu. But I want to know how can I automate the Mouse action. Do i need to use clickAndHold method of mouse or draganddrop method of mouse action  class. Please  mention a piece of code for ease of understanding

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class SelectText {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[5]/span/center/div[3]/div/div"));
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.moveToElement(element, 0, 0)
            .clickAndHold()
            .moveByOffset(50, 0)
            .release()
            .perform();
    }

}
```

1)Here I am trying to select Google text that is below the search button

2)I am finding the element and then moving to the element at position (0,0)which is the top left corner of the element,

3)By using click and hold I am moving to the right using moveByOffset function by 50, you can vary x and y parameters of moveByOffset function based on your text selection area.

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Kumar  If I want to start from a particular location of text where there is no webelement. How to choose the locators to inspect

Comment: if your text is inside a paragraph <p> tag use find element by tag

Comment: Yes Kumar . The text I want to select is present inside the <p> tag.

Comment: you can use the same code, just replace find element by line of code with find element by tag. use movetoelement and movebyoffset to go to a particular text and select it.

Comment: If there are multiple <p> tags. I mean if there are multiple paragraphs in a page then How Selenium will inspect for multiple <p > tagged Elemnets.

Comment: Your question started with "How to select the group of text in Selenium". I gave you general idea how to approach. now you need to try and experiment and then get back if you are stuck, provide html for your problem. I feel you are just trying to get information without trying any thing.

Comment: can you provide the html of your problem and the code you have tried, it will help you get your problem solved.

Comment: <head>
<body>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
<article id="chapter2" epub:type="chapter">
<header>
<section id="CFA0069-L-s01" epub:type="subchapter">
<section id="CFA0069-R-s01" epub:type="subchapter">
<p>
<h1 id="CFA0069-R-s01-h1">Standard I: Professionalism</h1>
<section id="CFA0069-R-s01-01">
<section id="CFA0069-R-s01-02">
<p>
<h2 id="CFA0069-R-s01-02-h2" class="not-stacked">Guidance</h2>
<section id="CFA0069-R-L1">
<p>Members and candidates must understand the applicable laws and regulations of the countries.</p>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<section id="">
<section id="">
<section id="">

Comment: WebElement highlightText = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='CFA0006-R-s01-01']/xhtml:p[2]"));
  
  Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    
        actions.moveToElement(highlightText, 0, 0)
            .clickAndHold()
            .moveByOffset(50, 0)
            .release()
            .perform();
  
  
 }